# How do i make my own server on linux?

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver

Its sounds dumb but i have to make a web server as my OS course project in university. I am very confused what to do with it , How to start i read articles but cant picked the one whether i use apache to make my server who host my file present in my laptop , Should this be informative [Server](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2008/01/tutorial-setup-your-own-self-hosted-simple-web-server-for-free/).
I am using ubuntu desktop 15.04

Help !

Answer (score 0):

A server is just a machine that provides some sort of service.

If you want to have a web server, that serves a webpage or some files, you can simply install an application server like Apache or Nginx.

So first get your Ubuntu installed and then install and configure Apache (or other).

To install Apache is as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then on your web browser navigate to http://localhost/ or http://server-ip-address/.

If you plan on having a more "complex" server with an application server, a relational database and PHP for example, that is called a LAMP server (Linux Apache Mysql PHP), and you can read all about that here [Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

Comment: I just have to MAKE a simple server that host my files , That's it ! 
The confusion is whether i make it or i used apache and configured it and then used it , What your advice to me ?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Install and configure apache, on the apache files directory (something like /var/www/html) place your files, then simply open your web browser on the IP of your server. If you plan on serving files you can also consider setting up an FTP server.

Comment: okay i'll try on apache

Comment: If you have time and if you are interested you can research a bit for berkeley sockets and the http protocol and simply write an own web server (a very basic one) in your prefered language (e.g. there are easy examples for java or C# web servers with berkeley sockets)